# Can I have a conversation with Allah without asking for anything?

Tags: allah

Can I come back home from a long day, pray isha and after tasleem I put my hand up like dua hands and talk to Allah. Talking to Allah in a way like "Dear Allah, you know everything that I did and feel today but I would like to tell you how my day went anyway because you are the best at listening to me like a best friend. Today this ... and that ... happened, and something funny also happened * laugh *..., and at the end say thank you to Allah and end the conversation.

Comment: Allah's your friend, of course you can!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. And that's very good. You can talk to him in a friendly way at any time, without asking for anything. He hears all our words.
I would like to draw your attention to the verses of the Qur'an about Moses' conversation with God. How does God speak to Moses in the desert? Friendly .... What is this in your hand? And Moses explains about his staff. Did not God know that Moses What is in his hand ?! Yes, God knew. But he wanted Moses to talk to him in a friendly way and talk and talk.